# NodeJS + Express Memory leak on multipart upload

Tags: node.js, memory, file-upload, express, memory-leaks

I'm really surprised with the behavior of Node + Express in a really simple task.

What im trying to do is just to **upload a file through a multipart form**.
After the file upload, the node memory increases too much (coincidentally about 60 mb, aprox same size of the uploaded file) and remain until restart the node process. I guess that the garbage collector should free that allocated memory, but apparently not. Some info:

- Node v: 0.10.33
- Express v: 4.11.1
- Before upload Node RAM = 19.9 MB
- After upload Node RAM = 79.9 MB
- Uploaded file size: 60 MB

To explain it I created a project from scratch with Node and Express, using

```
express -ejs .
```

I uploaded this example project to GitHub (including node_modules) just to clarify and you to have a snapshot: https://github.com/CesarTrigo/node-express-memory-leak

As you can see I have created two routes, one for the form and the other to print the req content.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("/UPLOAD");
    console.log(req);
    res.end();

});

module.exports = router;
```

So the problem is that after 10 or 12 big uploads, the Node process crashes because the RAM remains increasing and breaks out of memory.

What am I missing? Please, a little help would be welcome!!!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you're submitting a multipart request? You're not using any multipart request-handling middleware in that project on github...

Comment: Thants right @mscdex, in this example has not even been necessary to handle multipart request. The simple fact of receiving grows memory.

Comment: How fast are you triggering the uploads? I just downloaded your example and was not able to reproduce the issue with a 100mb file. Granted, I was manually upload once every 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for reply Youself. I can reproduce the Issue with only one upload. Which node versión are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue with the `console.log()` of the image. Online I found others mentioning that **[`console.log()` was leaking memory](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/KtONbpVV68U).**

Try doing another action like saving it to a file and see if that causes the major memory leaks that you're experiencing now.